# Open Microsoft Query file without active connection

Tags: sql, view, odbc, ms-query

I'm completely new to MS-QUERY. I am trying to open .dqy file in MS-Query.

When opening the file, I get an error mentioning: Name of datasource is not found or no default ODBC-driver is selected.

I understand that because this is an older file, the ODBC connection that was setup initially, is no longer available. I want to redirect the query to an active ODBC-connection to make it work again. Another approach would be to build the query again, based on a new dqy-file with an active ODBC. However, because of the error, I can't open the query design within MS-query so I can't create a new dqy-file as I don't know how the query looks like. I only know that it is needed.

My question is rather broad, but are there other ways to view the query design without having the ODBC-connection available where the MS-query was based upon?

Comment: Have you tried opening the .dqy file in a text editor to see if you can modify the contents that way?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of @Gord Thompson, I was able to open the file using notepad. In the file I was able to modify the connection string and able to copy the query design to use in a new query.